# App Force Closing on calling doInBackground for getting a JSON file from the server

Tags: php, android, json

I want to get a JSON data created on calling a PHP file on the server and store the JSON data to SQLite database in the android app. But when I click the button to execute the fetching process the app force closes. 
This is my code sample

```
 else if (type.equals("getjson")){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput((true));
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result ="";
            String line="";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
      //      return result;
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject;

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String tempEid = jsonObject.getString("eid");

                    String tempEname = jsonObject.getString("ename");

                    boolean res = db.insertDb(tempEid, tempEname);
                    return String.valueOf(res);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.iamaravind.dhishnareg, PID: 14847
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
       at com.iamaravind.dhishnareg.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:41)
       at com.iamaravind.dhishnareg.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:31)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Please check whether the code for getting the json is correct.

```
    public void getJson(View view)
{
    String type = "getjson";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type);
}
```

This is the Calling function.

Comment: try it
jsonObject = jsonArray[i].getJSONObject();

Comment: The problem is here, which is that line in your code (Line 41)? Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                           at com.iamaravind.dhishnareg.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:41

Comment: protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[1]; // Line 41

Comment: Thanks Juan for spotting out the error line . Created a new file for fetching the json and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return from inside the for loop in every condition.

You should remove the line `return String.valueOf(res);` from inside the for loop and handle error with a different logic. You may return false if res == false, But not unconditionally. Otherwise there would be no use of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Nabin for spotting that :).

Comment: I would use a JSON parsing library like GSON. Parsing JSON manually is not fun ;D